# How to popup a document picker in ios and macos using catalyst

Tags: ios, swiftui, mac-catalyst

I'm trying to popup a document picker using mac catalyst, but all I get is a blank screen.

All works well on ios 13.2.2 on iPad and iPhone, but not on macos 10.15.1 catalina.

Does anyone knows how to popup a document picker in both ios and macos using catalyst?

with my entitlements file having:

```
<key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
<false/>
```

Here is the test code that shows the problem.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
@State var isFilePickerShown = false

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button(action: { self.isFilePickerShown.toggle() }) {
            Image(systemName: "rectangle.and.paperclip").resizable().frame(width: 70, height: 70)
        }
    }.sheet(isPresented: $isFilePickerShown, onDismiss: {self.isFilePickerShown = false}) {
        DocPickerViewController(callback: self.filePicked, onDismiss: { self.isFilePickerShown = false })
    }
}

func filePicked(_ url: URL) {
    print("\nThe url is: \(url)")
}

}

struct DocPickerViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

private let docTypes: [String] = ["com.adobe.pdf", "public.text", "public.composite-content"]
var callback: (URL) -> ()
private let onDismiss: () -> Void

init(callback: @escaping (URL) -> (), onDismiss: @escaping () -> Void) {
    self.callback = callback
    self.onDismiss = onDismiss
}

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator { Coordinator(self) }

func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIDocumentPickerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<DocPickerViewController>) {
}

func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIDocumentPickerViewController {
    let controller = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: docTypes, in: .import)
    controller.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    controller.delegate = context.coordinator
    return controller
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
    var parent: DocPickerViewController
    init(_ pickerController: DocPickerViewController) {
        self.parent = pickerController
    }
    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
        parent.callback(urls[0])
        parent.onDismiss()
    }
    func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
        parent.onDismiss()
    }
}
}
```

I got something going with the following code. But really this is
a messy business and I feel this is not the answer.

Now I have the same problem trying to display
a UIActivityViewController. I can display it on Mac using the same approach but 
I can't control where it shows up. It's always at (0,0).

```
struct FilePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

private let docTypes: [String] = ["com.adobe.pdf", "public.text", "public.composite-content"]
private let controller: FilePickerController?

var callback: (URL) -> ()

private let onDismiss: () -> Void

init(callback: @escaping (URL) -> (), onDismiss: @escaping () -> Void) {
    self.callback = callback
    self.onDismiss = onDismiss
    self.controller = FilePickerController(documentTypes: docTypes, mode: .import)
}

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    return Coordinator(self)
}

func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: FilePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<FilePicker>) { }

func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> FilePickerController {
    return controller!
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, FilePickerControllerDelegate {
    var parent: FilePicker

    init(_ filePicker: FilePicker) {
        self.parent = filePicker
        super.init()
        self.parent.controller?.delegate = self
    }

    func documentPicker(_ controller: FilePickerController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
        parent.callback(urls[0])
        parent.onDismiss()
    }

    func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: FilePickerController) {
        parent.onDismiss()
    }
}
}


protocol FilePickerControllerDelegate: class {
func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: FilePickerController)
func documentPicker(_ controller: FilePickerController, 
didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL])
}

class FilePickerController: UIViewController, UIDocumentPickerDelegate {

weak var delegate: FilePickerControllerDelegate?

let viewController: UIDocumentPickerViewController?

public init(documentTypes: [String], mode: UIDocumentPickerMode) {
    viewController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: documentTypes, in: mode)
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

required public init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    viewController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(coder: coder)
    super.init(coder: coder)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if let viewController = viewController {
        viewController.delegate = self
        self.present(viewController, animated: animated)
    }
}

func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
    self.dismiss(animated: false) {
        self.delegate?.documentPicker(self, didPickDocumentsAt: urls)
    }
}

func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
    self.dismiss(animated: false) {
        self.delegate?.documentPickerWasCancelled(self)
    }
}

}
```

I call it like this:

```
.sheet(isPresented: $isShown, onDismiss: {self.isShown = false}) {
        #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
            FilePicker(callback: self.filePicked, onDismiss: { self.isShown = false })
        #else
            DocPickerViewController(callback: self.filePicked, onDismiss: { self.isShown = false })
        #endif
    }
```

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 3):

Workaround: present picker controller for catalyst

```
UIApplication.shared.firstKeyWindow?.rootViewController!.present(self.picker.controller!, animated: true)

extension UIApplication {
    public var firstKeyWindow: UIWindow? {
        windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For all with code from `hstdt` and `workingdog`.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isFilePickerShown = false
    @State private var picker = DocumentPicker()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.isFilePickerShown.toggle()
                 #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
                UIApplication.shared.windows[0].rootViewController!.present(self.picker.viewController, animated: true)
                #endif
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "rectangle.and.paperclip").resizable().frame(width: 70, height: 70)
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isFilePickerShown, onDismiss: {self.isFilePickerShown = false}) {
            DocPickerViewController(callback: self.filePicked, onDismiss: { self.isFilePickerShown = false })
        }
    }

    func filePicked(_ url: URL) {
        print("\nThe url is: \(url)")
    }
}
```

and now create new swiftui file `DocumentPicker` for MacOS:

```
import SwiftUI

final class DocumentPicker: NSObject, UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = UIDocumentPickerViewController

    lazy var viewController:UIDocumentPickerViewController = {
        // For picked only folder
        let vc = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.folder"], in: .open)
        // For picked every document
//        let vc = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.data"], in: .open)
        // For picked only images
//        let vc = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.image"], in: .open)
        vc.allowsMultipleSelection = false
//        vc.accessibilityElements = [kFolderActionCode]
//        vc.shouldShowFileExtensions = true
        vc.delegate = self
        return vc
    }()

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<DocumentPicker>) -> UIDocumentPickerViewController {
        viewController.delegate = self
        return viewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIDocumentPickerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<DocumentPicker>) {
    }
}

extension DocumentPicker: UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
        print(urls)
    }

    func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true) {
        }
        print("cancelled")
    }
}
```

This code popup a document picker in both iOS and MacOS using catalyst.
With MacOS Catalyst work with `DocumentPicker` Class and with iOS with `DocPickerViewController` write by `workingdog` (see `workingdog` post above)

Answer (score 3):

That's the example from Cesare Piersigilli on GitHub: https://github.com/AndreasPrang/Catalyst-File-Picker

Answer (score 0):

if target macos 11+ then try to use .fileImporter presentation modifier

```
.fileImporter(isPresented: $showDocumentPicker,
                      allowedContentTypes: [.folder],
                      allowsMultipleSelection: true)
        { result in
            // processing results Result<[URL], Error>
        }
```